# How can I automatically create a virtualenv with setup.py?

Tags: python, pycharm, setup.py, python-venv

In my github practice project, I set up it's own virtualenv by using the command `virtualenv env`.

And I made a `setup.py` file using the PyCharm IDE.

But the `setup.py` didn't make a virtualenv automatically when I cloned the project in other PyCharm project.

I want to create my project's virtualenv automatically with `setup.py` or by another method.

I tried searching for information, but I couldn't find what is required to automatically create a virtualenv.

Which thing do i need to know?

Comment: `setup.py` specifies how to install your library or app for the users of your app. it does not specify environment for developing your app. PyCharm probably has own mechanism for that.

Comment: @DimaTisnek Thank you for your comment. 
I had the wrong knowledge about that.

Answer (score 1):

a quick solution is just to execute the bash command

```
import os
os.system("virtualenv env")
```

as specified in the comments, this is **not** something you would usually want to do: PyCharm has its own way to manage virtualenvs

Comment: you can upvote or put as a correct answer if you find it useful